# Printing a subset of a web page via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, printing

Is it possible to print only a section of the DOM via JS?

If the only way is to specify a print stylesheet, I presume the print stylesheet can be applied dynamically, immediately before the browser print functionality invocation?

Comment: nope you can't load it just in time. the best thing to do is load it all the time.

Comment: But the stylesheet will have to be dynamic unless I do something clever with data attributes and attr selectors.

Comment: it would help to know what your end game is.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
self.printDomElement = function(selector) {
    var newWindow = window.open("", "Test", "width=500,height=500,scrollbars=1,resizable=1");
    var sectionOfDom = $(selector);
    newWindow.document.open();
    for (var i = 0; i < sectionOfDom.length; i++) {
        newWindow.document.write(sectionOfDom[i].innerHTML);
    }
    newWindow.document.close();
    newWindow.print();
    newWindow.close();
};
```

EDIT: From what I've read, an iFrame will work only if it doesn't violate the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). There is a different way to access the `innerHTML` property of iFrames as well, so you would have to have a conditional to access it differently if it's an iFrame.

Here is the edited code to handle iframe content:

```
self.printDomElement = function(selector) {
        var newWindow = window.open("", "Test", "width=500,height=500,scrollbars=1,resizable=1");
        var sectionOfDom = $(selector);
        newWindow.document.open();
        for (var i = 0; i < sectionOfDom.length; i++) {
            if ($(sectionOfDom[i]).is('iframe')) {
                try {
                    newWindow.document.write(sectionOfDom[i].contentDocument.body.innerHTML);
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log('Caught exception with message: [' + err.message + '] while trying to write content to print window.');
                }
            } else {
                newWindow.document.write(sectionOfDom[i].innerHTML);
            }
        }
        newWindow.document.close();
        newWindow.print();
        newWindow.close();
    };
```

Comment: I guess popup blockers might cause issues with this. An iframe would also work?